# How do I loop through JavaScript objects in Jade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, pug

Node.js - Jade - socket.io - jQuery - JSON

Inside my "index.jade" I have the following code where "results" data comes from the backend as JSON:

```
extends layout

block content
 ul
 // more jade html here

 script.
  socket.on('results', function(results) {
   results.forEach(function(item){
   name = item.name;
   $('ul').append('<li>'+name+'</li>');
  });
 });
```

This works but, because I will have a lot more content and tags to push inside "ul" later on, I don't want to have a massive block of concatenated html inside "append()".

I really like the Jade format instead:

```
ul
 each val, index in results
 li= results[index].name
```

Although I can't write this last code in my "block content" because "socket.on('results')" has not been triggered yet and throws an error.

Is there a an elegant way to write this?

Comment: You could re-render the layout once the data is returned. On the initial render you could just render a loading spinner or some kind of empty state. Once the data comes, re-render and include all of the names

Comment: it's more efficient appending once (big block html) than numerous times with small blocks

Comment: Thanks. Essentially my question is: instead of having a long and ugly append('<li class="name">name: '+name+'<ul class="info"><li>age: '+age+'</li></ul></li>') etc… can I have an append(template) where template is a separate piece of jade saved elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jade on the client, too. Take a look at `jadeify`:
https://github.com/domenic/jadeify

With that, you would have your `row.jade`, for example, and on each socket message, append a row:

```
var template = require('views/row.jade');
var $ul = $('ul');
socket.on('row',  function(item) {
    $uk.append(template(item));
});
```

Then just adapt the socket to emit one row at a time.